# ESB Basic Doubts

Tags: esb, wso2-esb

I am new to ESB, I learned and tried Proxy Service and i was able to deploy my first Proxy Service (Pass Through Proxy).

There are several steps I did, registering the wsdl and xsd into registry and and using those details to make the proxy up and running.

Is that the only way or is there any other way to deploy the application.

Since I have around 50 services **(actual service, created using apache CXF and deployed in apache tomcat)** up and running, and i need to create proxy for this **(a proxy which will redirect to correct endpoint based on the input).**

What kind of proxy am i supposed to create?

Do i need to register all the wsdl, xsd into wso2 server one by one or is there any other way **(something like creating a archive and upload into server)**.

What is ESB Config project in developer studio??

https://sites.google.com/site/samplefilesforwso2/testing.zip

Please find a project which contains 2 simplest service and i wanted to deploy in this in server and create single proxy which will delegate the call to this services, How to achieve it??

Is there any tutorial available, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

In [Wso2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/), one of the project type called ESB Config Project to save all the ESB related artifacts such as Proxy Services, Endpoints, Sequences, local Entries and Synapse Configurations.
to refer further on this topic please refer to [1]

[1]http://wso2.org/project/developer-studio/docs/esb_category.html